# Switching a JButton from one JPanel to another Jpanel in Swing

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jpanel, jbutton

I try to drag and drop a Button from on Panel to another. Everything is Custom already. But I think I'm missing something.
Both have "GridLayouts"
And both are 100% filed with Buttons.
I have already Implemented a MouseMotionListener which works really well. I am able to move the Buttons around inside their Panel. BUT if I want to leave the Panel the Button disappears.
I'm able to move it back if I keep it dragged but I can't see the Button once it leaves the Panel.

Is there an easy fix to this, which I am missing?

This is my first time creating a minimal example, I hope it's ok

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;

//this class works perfekt
class TileRackListener implements MouseMotionListener {

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent argEvent) {
        System.out.println("(" + argEvent.getX() + "," + argEvent.getY() + ")");

        if (argEvent.getX() < 0 || argEvent.getY() < 0) {
            Rectangle objBounds = argEvent.getComponent().getBounds();
            argEvent.getComponent().setLocation(objBounds.x + argEvent.getX(),
                    objBounds.y + argEvent.getY());
        } else {

            Rectangle objBounds = argEvent.getComponent().getBounds();
            if (objBounds.x <= objBounds.x + argEvent.getX()
                    && objBounds.x + argEvent.getX() <= objBounds.x
                            + objBounds.width
                    && objBounds.y <= objBounds.y + argEvent.getY()
                    && objBounds.y + argEvent.getY() <= objBounds.y
                            + objBounds.height) {
                argEvent.getComponent().setLocation(
                        objBounds.x + argEvent.getX(),
                        objBounds.y + argEvent.getY());
            } else {
                argEvent.getComponent().setLocation(argEvent.getX(),
                        argEvent.getY());
            }
        }

        argEvent.getComponent().transferFocus();
        ;

        argEvent.getComponent().repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

class ButtonCell extends JButton {
    private char letter;
    private int value;
    private Image iconImage;

    public void setIconImage(Image image) {
        this.iconImage = image;
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        setIcon(icon);
        setDisabledIcon(icon);
    }

}

class TestPane extends JPanel {

    //Custom Motion Listener
    private TileRackListener motionListener = new TileRackListener();
    private ButtonCell[] field;
    private static final int COLUMN_COUNT =2 ;
    private int width = 100;
    private int height = 32;
    private int buttonSize = 50;
    public TestPane() {
        field = new ButtonCell[COLUMN_COUNT];
        setBounds(new Rectangle(width, height));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 7));
        setBackground(new Color(139, 69, 19));

        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            field[i] = new ButtonCell();
            field[i].setBackground(new Color(139, 69, 19));
            field[i].setBounds(new Rectangle(buttonSize, buttonSize));
            field[i].setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("Text"));
            field[i].addMouseMotionListener(motionListener);
            add(field[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
                frame.setBounds(new Rectangle(200, 200));
                frame.setLayout(null);

                TestPane first = new TestPane();
                first.setLocation(10, 10);
                TestPane second = new TestPane();
                second.setLocation(10, 100);
                frame.add(first);

                frame.setVisible(true);

                frame.add(second);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I added what you asked for. I hope ok, otherwise please say it